# Should I compare outer types in equals implementation for inner class

Tags: java, comparison, inner-classes

When I use eclipse's automatic generation of `hashCode` and `equals`, the generated code contains a check for the outer type:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Inner other = (Inner) obj;
    if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
        return false;
    if (innerField == null) {
        if (other.innerField != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!innerField.equals(other.innerField))
        return false;
    return true;
}

private Outer getOuterType() {
    return Outer.this;
}
```

Is it really necessary? Isn't `getClass() != obj.getClass()` enough?

Comment: good question, this seems to imply that different instances of outer an contain the same instance of inner, which does not make sense, as an inner class is linked directly to its outer

Comment: Ok, looking at the question I duplicated, I understood that I got confused by the method name `getOuterType`. It actually compares the outer type **instance** (which makes perfect sense) rather then the outer type itself...